# Serialization of Control characters

Tags: c#, unicode, xml-serialization, ascii

In my program I wish to save a list of objects the user might have. Each object will have a particular value, much like an ID or reference. I thought converting the numerical value of the object to a ASCII character to be saved to disk was a good idea.

Here is my object array:

```
public short[,] Data = new short[5,5];
```

I fill it with random numbers (between 42 and 100, representing the object IDs the user might have) then convert the data to ASCII characters before serializing it to file:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii <= 4; ii++)
    {
        Data[i, ii] = (short)Rand.Next(42, 100); //random numbers to get random characters
        Save_Data.ASCII += (char)Data[i, ii]; //Converting to ASCII and adding to Class which will be saved to file
    }
}

XmlSerializer Writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Save_Data)); 

using (FileStream file = File.OpenWrite(myfile)) 
{
    Writer.Serialize(file, Save_Data);
}
```

When reading the file I get no errors and can convert the data back into a list of the values. *Although the original data is in an array I have not included the code to get the list back into the array*

```
Save_Data fList; 

XmlSerializer Reader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Save_Data)); 

using (FileStream input = File.OpenRead(myfile)) 
{
    fList = Reader.Deserialize(input) as Save_Data; //Reading in the data
}

string Final = "";

byte[] ASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fList.World);

foreach (Byte b in ASCII)
{
    Final += " " + b.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(Final);
```

This works fine. **However**, if I extend the range of my random function i.e:

```
Rand.Next(12,100);
```

to include other ASCII characters such as control characters, I get an error when reading the file to my program:

> There is an error in XML document (x, y).

(x = Row, Y = Col)

It later states the exception being:

> "'**V**', hexadecimal value **W**, is an invalid character. Line **X**, position
>   **Y.**"

V = An ASCII control character

W = The Hexadecimal value of this control character

X = Line Number

Y = Position Value

Are control characters unserializable? If so, is there a way round this?

**On a second note:**  This method, without control characters, will only give me <60 possible object ID/Reference numbers. I thought it would be better to perhaps use Unicode as this can support many more characters giving me a bigger range. With my current code is there a way of using Unicode over ASCII?  I apologize in advance if this is a very basic question as I am fairly new to Stack...

Comment: michaelb958 is correct in his answer. I would also very strongly encourage you to explore more about the rationale of XML and in particular how to use it well. It's not just a textual dump: the tags are supposed to self-describe the data, so a human has some chance to "read" an XML file's meaning.Dumping arrays of objects in this way isn't self-describing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to create a byte array sized on the dimensions of your short array and fill it with (byte)Data[i, ii].

Then use Convert.ToBase64String(byte_array) and you will have a string than can safely be used in an XML document.

For deserialization use Covert.FromBase64String(xml_value) to get back the byte array, and loop to fill your short array.

Comment: How can you convert a char to a byte? A char is 16bits and a byte is only 8?

Comment: True, but the characters in use (cause you said so) are always in ascii range, in other words within the byte values range.

Comment: Oh ok. I was just using the example you suggested of casting them to char, but that doesn't work. Thanks anyway however.

Comment: Ooops. My bad. I changed (char)Data[i, ii] to (byte)Data[i, ii]. It should work. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just what I was looking for. Think it's actually `Convert.FromBase64String(xml_value)` but regardless, thanks!

Comment: Correction is made. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML), most ASCII control characters are invalid when embedded raw into an XML document. Entity-escaping them with `&#DECIMAL;` or `&#xHEX;` is the preferred way to include these characters.

Comment: Using character references to get control characters only works in XML 1.1, which many tools won't read. And you still can't get the nul character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're embedding binary data into a text document.  Either do the full thing in binary serialization, or convert your numbers into strings via the `.ToString()` method.

If you change your object array into a single-dimensional array, then you can simply replace your `string Save_Data.ASCII` with a `short[] Save_Data.Data` and the `XmlSerializer` will serialize that directly without you needing to manually convert anything to a string.  That's the easiest thing to do IMO.

WRT unicode, that will have the same problem as the original, it's still binary embedded into text.  So if one of your chars is for instance `'<'`, the XML will think it's the start of a new tag and now your XML is invalid, unicode or not.  The solution in my 2nd paragraph avoids the problem completely, as the ints are encoded as decimal strings before serializing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just serializing the array directly?

I don't think there's much reason for you to try to do the XML Serializer's job for it. The worst you should have to do is flatten your 5x5 array into a 25 element one dimensional array.

Comment: You can't serialize a 2D array.